# Получить значение ячейки DataGrid, вызвавшей событие CellEditEnding, WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Необходимо при событии CellEditEnding проверить введенное значение на корректность, но откуда взять это значение? Делаю так:

```
private void dataGridInputMatrix_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
        int rowIndex = e.Row.GetIndex();
        int columnIndex = e.Column.DisplayIndex;

        string value = ((DataRowView)dataGridInputMatrix.Items[rowIndex]).Row[columnIndex].ToString();
}
```

Но при таком варианте значение там не введенное, а старое. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если изменения вносятся в текстовую ячейку,  то попробуйте так:

```
var newValue  = ((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text
```

Comment: Да, это именно то, что нужно! Спасибо!